# Uncaught SodiumException: Argument 3 must be CRYPTO_SIGN_PUBLICKEYBYTES long

Tags: php, cryptography, digital-signature, libsodium, ed25519

I'm using a frontend library to create a digital signature and using my PHP backend to verify the signature.

I'm using the Ed25519 signature system so, I'm using this PHP [library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-sign-detached.php).

I'm using the PHP code below to verify the signature but I'm getting the error `Uncaught SodiumException: Argument 3 must be CRYPTO_SIGN_PUBLICKEYBYTES long.`

```
if (sodium_crypto_sign_verify_detached(hex2bin($wallet_signature), $description, $wallet_address)) {
    error_log('The message is authentic.');
} else {
    error_log('The message has been tampered with!');
}
```

The `Argument 3` is my public key which is `zGmof8SeyvHKnSEWv4i2mVv7MYe85D3zZqsTBjsKXSV`

A further investigation reveals that the CRYPTO_SIGN_PUBLICKEYBYTES is this -> `const CRYPTO_SIGN_PUBLICKEYBYTES = 32;`

How may I solve this?

Comment: strlen('zGmof8SeyvHKnSEWv4i2mVv7MYe85D3zZqsTBjsKXSV') is 43 not 32.

Comment: You obviously need to decode `zGmof8SeyvHKnSEWv4i2mVv7MYe85D3zZqsTBjsKXSV`. It doesn't seem to be Base64, possibly Base58 (which results in 32 bytes when decoded).

Comment: @Topaco Do you mean I need to change `zGmof8SeyvHKnSEWv4i2mVv7MYe85D3zZqsTBjsKXSV` to base64? It's a blockchain wallet address and the public key comes with app. I wonder if it's possible to change it.

Comment: No, I mean that you should try a Base58 decoding. This will return 32 bytes as requested by the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, the @Topaco has the right suggestion, you need to decode *Base58* `$wallet_address`. This is the working example:

```php
use Tuupola\Base58;

/**
 * @param string $signature - base58 encoded signature
 * @param string $message - an original plain message without encoding
 * @param string $walletAddress - wallet public key
 * @return bool
 * @throws \SodiumException
 */
 public function verifyMessage(string $signature, string $message, string $walletAddress): bool {
    $base58 = new Base58(["characters" => Base58::BITCOIN]);
    return sodium_crypto_sign_verify_detached(
       $base58->decode($signature),
       $message,
       $base58->decode($walletAddress)
    );
 }
```

for decoding is used the [tuupola/base58](https://github.com/tuupola/base58) package.

I noticed that this is an old question, but when I was trying to find a solution, I couldn't find anything concrete with an example. Hope this code will help someone.